# Add vcs-url label to pod in openshift with app.openshift.io/vcs-uri annotation

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, helm3

I am trying to add git repo url to pod annotation in openshift. However deployment complains about special character is not allowed as value for `app.openshift.io/vcs-uri`

Here is the error:

`Deploy failed: The Deployment "test-app" is invalid: metadata.labels: Invalid value: "git://github.com/myrepo/testrepo.git": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue', or 'my_value', or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')`

Here is my sample helm chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: test-poc
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: poc-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: angular
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.openshift.io/runtime: angularjs
    app.openshift.io/vcs-uri: "git://github.com/myrepo/testrepo.git"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  .......
```

Comment: Did you tries removing the quotes? -> git://github.com/myrepo/testrepo.git with no quotes?

Comment: As mentioned by the error message, label value cannot use /, : . So you should use annotations instead.

Comment: I tried without quotes and faced same error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have special characters like `@` or `/` in your label value or name. The error message clearly states that:

```
consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '' or '.'
```

There is even a regex in the error message:

```
'(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?'
```

You can plug that Regular Expression into any choice of tool like regex101.com and check if your label value works.

However, annotations are a little less restricted as described in the [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/#syntax-and-character-set)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Rick Rackow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6336357/rick-rackow) mentioned, `app.openshift.io/vcs-uri` should be an annotation, not a label.

Try something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: test-poc
  annotations:
    app.openshift.io/vcs-uri: "git://github.com/myrepo/testrepo.git"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: poc-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: angular
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.openshift.io/runtime: angularjs
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  .......
```

See: https://github.com/redhat-developer/app-labels/blob/master/labels-annotation-for-openshift.adoc